# android Observer method update not work

Tags: java, android

I use observer pattern

recently , In my main class,

MainActivity.class

```
static private AutoObservable observable;   //global variable 
private Agency agency = null; //global variable

@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   observable = agency;
   observable.addObserver(new Observerclass(agency.RoomName()));
}
```

AutoObservable.class

```
public class AutoObservable extends Observable {
@Override
public void notifyObservers(Object data) {
    super.setChanged();
    super.notifyObservers(data);
    super.clearChanged();
}
}
```

Observerclass.class

```
public class Observerclass implements Observer {
   private final String roomName;
   public Observerclass(String roomName) {
         this.roomName = roomName;
   }

   @Override
   public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
      . . .   // not work ..
   }
```

perhaps,, permission problem?.. 
please advice for me.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to override `notifyObservers()`, so, remove this code block from `AutoObservable`

```
@Override
public void notifyObservers(Object data) {
    super.setChanged();
    super.notifyObservers(data);
    super.clearChanged();
}
```

Instead, do something like in `AutoObservable.java`

```
public void onSomeEvent() {
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(data);
}
```

And, from `MainActivity` call `Observer` instance like

```
observable.onSomeEvent();
```

Comment: thanks, and I have a question.   `notifyObservers(data)`   data is `onSomeEvent(Object data)` is right?

Comment: Yes this makes sense, if you want to pass different data from different observer.